# Unable to LoadLibrary ssl for Android, getting UnsatifiedLinkError

Tags: android, dynamic, openssl, shared-libraries

I have built OpenSSL for Android(using ndk-build) and have linked it to my program. Compilation and linking works, but I get a run time error of UnsatisfiedLinkError.
More specifically, the program breaks on this code:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity 
{     // load the library - name matches jni/Android.mk   
    static {     
        System.loadLibrary("crypto2");   
        System.loadLibrary("ssl2");   // <=BREAKS HERE!
        System.loadLibrary("Test");   
        }
```

It specifically breaks when loading ssl2, so it seems it was able to load crypto2.
I think I need to tell ssl2 that it use cryto2, I tried to do that on the Android.mk file, but it didn't help.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libcrypto2
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := OpenSSL/libcrypto2.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libssl2
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := OpenSSL/libssl2.so
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libcrypto2
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)   # Here we give our module name and source file(s)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := D:/DevelopTools/OpenSSL-WIN32/include $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../Framework/Applications/FW2Prototype $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../Graphics/Libraries/Common $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../Input/Libraries/Common $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../Audio/Libraries/Common $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../Audio/Libraries/NullAudio $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../Network/Libraries/Common
LOCAL_MODULE    := Test 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Test.cpp Reference.cpp JNINetwork.cpp JNIGraphics2D.cpp JNIInput.cpp JNIAudio.cpp Applications/FatalWars2/FatalWars2.cpp /../../../Audio/Libraries/NullAudio/NullAudio.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libcrypto2 libssl2
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Why not use [javax.net.ssl](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/package-summary.html)? It's built-in.

Comment: It's possible, but I thought it would be easier to use the native option right now, since I already have implemented and tested code for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" this.
I simpley built openssl into a single so file. I built both crypto and ssl statically, so ssl's dependency in crypto was hidden inside the static linking.
The issue is apparently that I couldn't load the prebuilt shared library ssl, because it was dependant of another prebuilt shared library(crypto). Maybe it's possible to load such libraries somehow, but my solution was just to static link crypto into ssl and then into a shared library called openssl.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more exactly what changes you made to the openssl library? I'm still stuck with the same unsatisfiedlinkerror...

Comment: I used these to link the two static libraries and modified the Android.mk files of these libs to make them static.
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libcrypto-static libssl-static
Unfortunantely I don't remember it so well, also notice that on windows you might have an issue with an argument too long for the command line. I think I eventually rented a linux cloud and built it there. Though the same applies with crypto and ssl being static.